# Files FFMPEG needs after compiling it (CentOS)

Tags: ffmpeg, centos

Background: I wanted to use the libfdk_aac library with FFMPEG as they say it is the highest quality one (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC). So that meant I had to compile FFMPEG from source.

That's all fine - I've done that and it all works.

But now I want to make a backup/image of the server, but keep it as small as possible. So I know I don't need all of source files.

But could anyone tell me whether I can just go ahead and delete everything apart from /usr/bin/ffmpeg (or whatever the path to the binary is)?

Or does that binary depend on a load of other libraries that have been built/buried within the system as part of the compilation process? I don't mind some - it's really just knowing how much I can safely get rid of without it randomly breaking due to a missing file weeks from now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the ffmpeg binary is built by statically linking its core libraries (libavcodec, libavformat [..]). A simple way to make sure is by looking at the size of the binary. Typically, more than 10MB = static, less than 1MB = dynamic.

However, it will still link dynamically any 3rd-party library such as libfdk_aac.

Saving the ffmpeg binary and libfdk_aac.so should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect, that explains it